# Sharepoint 2010 how to get all items in a folder contained in a list?

Tags: object-model

I have a list that contains folders.

Using c# and object model, how can I see if the folder contains any items, or return a collection of all the items in that folder.

Comment: Cant this above functionality done by using the services offered by sharepoint?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try the following code to get the items based on the folder,

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("site url"))
{
  using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
    SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder("/Docs/folder1");
    if(folder.ItemCount > 0)
    {
      SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("ListName");
      SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
      query.Folder = folder;
      SPListItemCollection listitem = list.GetItems(query);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Copycat :) But nothing really wrong because you tried to provided code example. I really hope that `SPListItemCollection = list.GetItems(query);` is typing error? And using `TryGetList` is meaningless because you don't check later if `list != null`. So if list doesn't exist your code will throw exception - same if you used `web.Lists["ListName"]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [SPQuery Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx) and define [SPQuery.Folder Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewattributes.aspx)

Comment: @soniiic when you down vote somebody it is polite to leave a comment

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach (SPFolder folder in list.Folders) {
    if (folder.ItemCount > 0) {
        foreach (SPFile file in folder.Files) {
            SPListItem item = file.Item;
            // Do stuff with your item here.
        }
        foreach (SPFolder subfolder in folder.SubFolders) {
            // Do stuff with your folder here.
            // Think about perhaps using recursion if you want to list the items from this folder and beyond
        }
    }
}
```

Because we're using foreach, we don't really need to check if the itemcount is more than 0.  But this is just an example to allow you to identify which folders have items and how you can access them

Comment: -1 - Right now I am working on one medium size library with ~15k documents in ~2k folders (2 levels deep) with size of few Gb. Running this code against it would be suicide. Using `SPFile` is also wrong if you don't want to change content of file. @soniiic please read [Best Practices: Common Coding Issues When Using the SharePoint Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687949(v=office.12).aspx#WorkingWithFoldersLists)

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have 15k or just one item, bad coding practices are always bad. Instead of whining you should learn to accept criticism. And after reading your comment I don't have any doubts about my down vote.