# Items return null value from query in sharepoint?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using this code to get items from the folder but it return `null` value in the `SPListItemCollection`.  What's the wrong in my code?

```cs
siteurl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList list = web.Lists["PoAlbum"];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType'/><Value Type='Computed'>Folder</Value></Eq></Where>";
DataTable listItemsTable = list.GetItems(query).GetDataTable();
string name = (listItemsTable.Rows[0]["NameOrTitle"]).ToString();      
SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder("/PoAlbum/" + name);
query.Folder = folder;
SPListItemCollection itms = list.GetItems(query);
reapeat.DataSource = itms.GetDataTable();
reapeat.DataBind();
```

Comment: Why you used `ContentType` in fieldref? is this column name?

Answer (score 1):

Use this as your query, finding the content type by name should be Value type `Text`:

```
 <Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType'/><Value Type='Text'>Folder</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy></OrderBy>
```

But my tip would be to first find the folder, without using Caml:

```
SPFolder myFolder = web.GetFolder("/LibraryName/FolderName");

if(myFolder != null){
    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title'/></OrderBy>";
    query.Folder = myFolder;
    query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'";
    SPListItemCollection col = list.GetItems(query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are giving condition to retrieve but you are not setting what fields need to show.
You should use `ViewFields` attribute for your query object. 
`query.ViewFields="<FieldReft name=""ABC""/><FieldRef name=""123""/>"`
If you use this line, in the result these fields will come.

This is samplequery

```
            myquery.Query= @"<Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name=""Title"" /></IsNotNull></Where>";
            myquery.ViewFields= @"<FieldRef Name=""Title"" />";
            myquery.ViewAttributes = " Scope='RecursiveAll";
            SPList querylist = web.Lists["ListName"];
            SPListItemCollection curItems = queryList.GetItems(myquery);
```

Modify your query accordingly. Will works fine.

Comment: Please give your feed back whether it is working or not?

Answer (score -2):

You should wrap your SPWeb code in a using block

```
using(SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web) {
   ...
}
```

This will reduce any memory leaks.

That said, there's an easier way to get the items in your folder.  [The answer on this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19847/sharepoint-2010-how-to-get-all-items-in-a-folder-contained-in-a-list) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is really bad practice since you shall not dispose the context web! It will severly impact performance